# Cannot change value in input fields

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, state

This is my code:

```
<Input
      onChange={(e) => someChange(e)}
      valid={check.length !== 0}
      invalid={check.length === 0}
      type="text"
      name="name"
      id="name"
      placeholder={something}
      value={props.someProp ? props.user.name : ''}
/>
```

So what happens here is when I enter into `props.someProp` my value gets retrieved. The problem is that I cannot **edit** that field. Please note that `user` object gets populated when this screen appears.

How can I make some kind of sanity check so I still get the value populated, but I can edit it afterwards?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot dynamically change `props` - you'll have to store those within `state`. Also can you provide the code for `someChange`

Comment: what does `someChange` do? maybe if you inverse the logic like `value={ props.user.name?  '' : props.someProp}` ?

Comment: `someChange` basically gets  `e.target.value` and stores it.

Comment: You also don't necessarily need valid AND invalid since one boolean will be the inverse of the other one

Comment: @MisterMister "and stores it" where? A parent component? The state of this component? There is not enough information in your question to get the correct answer, please include the entire parent component where <Input /> is being used, as well as any functions referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using stateless components *AND* `React 16.8+`, use `hooks`. This will allow your `stateless component` to contain `state`. React calls these `function components`.

> You might have previously known these as “stateless components”. We’re now introducing the ability to use React state from these, so we prefer the name “function components”.

#### Example

```
const Foo = props => {
  const [name, someChange] = useState(props.someProp ? props.user.name : '');

  return (
    <Input
      onChange={(e) => someChange(e.target.value)}
      value={name}
      ...
    />
  );
}
```

Documentation on hooks can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial state on component mount. After that the inputed value will be set on onChange.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state({name:''});
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({name: props.someProp ? props.user.name : ''});
}

someChange(e){
 let name = e.target.name;
 this.setState({[name]: e.target.value});
}

<Input
  onChange={(e) => someChange(e)}
  valid={check.length !== 0}
  invalid={check.length === 0}
  type="text"
  name="name"
  id="name"
  placeholder={something}
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```